# Inexact Binary Search: Given a Value, Find the Upper and Lower Index Of The Element Position

Tags: c#, binary-search

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<double, double>>`, **the list is sorted by `KeyValuePair.Key`**, so it's amendable to binary search. And I have a `double` object. Now, my task is to find the index of the `double` object. Here are the conditions that apply:

1. If that `double` object matches one of the `KeyValuePair.Key` within a specified tolerance, then the corresponding `KeyValuePair.Value` should be returned.
2. If the `double` object falls outside the max and min range of `KeyValuePair.Key`, then a 0 should be returned.
3. If the `double` object falls within the max min of the `KeyValuePair.Key`, but not matched any of the `KeyValuePair.Key` within a specified tolerance, then the get the average of the nearest upper and nearest lower `KeyValuePair.Value` ( as measured by `KeyValuePair.Key`).

I know that a binary search implementation is available in C#, but it is not exactly suited to my needs. I would like to ask is there any implementation out there that already meets my needs? I don't want to spend a few hours writing and debugging the code that other people has already written, debugged and perfected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done fairly easily with a comparer and a small wrapper around `List<T>.BinarySearch`:

```
static double Search(List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> list, double key) {
    int index = list.BinarySearch(
        new KeyValuePair<double, double>(key, 0), 
        new Comparer());

     // Case 1
     if (index >= 0)
         return list[index].Value;

     // NOTE: if the search fails, List<T>.BinarySearch returns the 
     // bitwise complement of the insertion index that would be used
     // to keep the list sorted.
     index = ~index;

     // Case 2
     if (index == 0 || index == list.Count)
        return 0;

     // Case 3
     return (list[index - 1].Value + list[index].Value) / 2;
 }

 class Comparer : IComparer<KeyValuePair<double, double>> {
     public int Compare(
         KeyValuePair<double, double> x, 
         KeyValuePair<double, double> y) 
     {
         if (Math.abs(x.Key - y.Key) < TOLERANCE)
             return 0;

         return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Only thing you might have to watch out for is id the list contains duplicates: If the List<T> contains more than one element with the same value, the method returns only one of the occurrences, and it might return any one of the occurrences, not necessarily the first one.

Comment: Nice one... I didn't realize that `BinarySearch` actually returns the bitwise complement of the insertion index... thanks!

Comment: @Mitch, for my application, all the `Key`s are unique, so there is no this worries.

Comment: @Mitch Excellent point! Also, thank you for pointing out that I forgot to handle the tolerance requirement in my original solution.